# How do I test Laravel Cashier Checkout Redirect in PEST PHP tests?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, php-pest

I have this subscribeToPlan method which will redirect the logged in user to Stripe's hosted checkout page.

```
public function subscribeToPlan(StripePlan $plan): \Laravel\Cashier\Checkout
{
    return auth()->user()->newSubscription('default', $plan->plan_id)->checkout([
        'success_url' => route('admin.plans.index'),
        'cancel_url' => route('admin.plans.index'),
    ]);
}
```

And this is the pest php test which I wrote:

```
test('User can subscribe to the Plan', function () {
    $plan = Plan::query()->first();
    $checkout = $this->actingAs($this->user)
        ->get(route('admin.plans.purchase', $plan));
   $this->assertInstanceOf(Checkout::class, $checkout);
});
```

But the problem is the subscribeToPlan method returns an instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse and not  \Laravel\Cashier\Checkout instance. How do I write this test case without mocking anything?

Comment: `$this->actingAs($this->user)->get(route('admin.plans.purchase', $plan));` ALWAYS returns a `Response` (redirect in your case). What do you want exactly to test? You could assert the redirection is working and done, there is not much to test here

Comment: I just want to test if it is actually going to the stripe checkout page.

Comment: Then, you should assert it is being redirected to the desired page, do a `dump($checkout)` (rename your variable to `$response`), and see what URL is going back to, and what variable is holding that value. You should use [`$response->assertRedirect($uri);`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#assert-redirect)

Comment: That's what I did finally.
Anyways thanks!

Comment: Awesome, that is what you have to do, if you are expecting a redirect, assert exactly that, nothing else